# Нажатие на кнопку enter

Tags: javascript, css, html5

Есть button и input:

```
<div class="img">
<button></button>
<input type="text" class="my-input">
</div>
```

Нужно, чтобы при нажатии клавиши "Enter", нажималась кнопка button, а поле input отчищалось (если в нём был текст).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/155188/trigger-a-button-click-with-javascript-on-the-enter-key-in-a-text-box

Comment: Да, но мне нужно ещё, чтобы после нажатия на Enter поле input text отчищалось. Как это сделать?

Comment: использовать button[type="reset"]

Comment: Как конкретно его использовать?

Comment: повесь на событие onkeyup элемента боди функцию-обработчик. если keyCode нажатой кнопки энтэровский, то пусть выполнится все те функции, которые выполняется при нажатии твоей кнопки button

Comment: Спасибо, но я уже нашёл решение ниже

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Задай Id кнопке и инпуту, подставь в код.

```
$("#id_of_textbox").keyup(function(event){
    if(event.keyCode == 13){
        $("#id_of_button").click();
        $(this).val('');
    }
});
```

Код из этого ответа, ссылку на который давали выше: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155188/trigger-a-button-click-with-javascript-on-the-enter-key-in-a-text-box

Answer (score 3):

***Пример:***

```js
$(document).keypress(function (e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
            document.getElementById("my-button").click();
            document.getElementById("my-input").value = "";
            alert("Pressed");
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="img">
<button id="my-button"> Press Me</button>
<input id="my-input" type="text" class="my-input">
</div>
```