# Запуск скрипта при нажатие на кнопку или ентер

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

напишите пожалуйста пример, который срабатывал бы при нажатие на button или enter ( причём button не должно содержать онклик)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Увы, определить нажат ли `enter` по кнопке - нельзя (думаю понятно почему).
По этому определение нажатия по кнопке должно происходить по документу (странице), а потом уже делать то же, что и при нажатии на кнопку.

```js
$(document).keypress(function(e){
  if(e.which==13) EnterButton();
});

$('button').on('click',function(){
  EnterButton();
});

function EnterButton() {
  console.info('enter');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<button>Press</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Да, вот такой код срабатывает:

```
            <html>
                <head>
                </head>
                <body>
                    <button id="mybtn">12345</button>
                </body>
            </html>
            <script>
            document.body.onclick = function (e) {
                e = e || event;
                target = e.target || e.srcElement;
                if ((target.id == "mybtn")){
                    alert(1);
                }
            }
            </script>
```

Как сделать, чтобы срабатывало при нажатии на Enter не знаю, никогда не использовал, вроде здесь что-то похожее:
[Нажатие на кнопку enter](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/561435/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BA%D1%83-enter)